# Proof of a simple isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, group-isomorphism

[image]

I'm having trouble with part b. I know I have to show that *a* map from *a* to *da* is an isomorphism from Z to *d*Z, but I don't know the general way to prove that a map is an isomorphism. I think I'm struggling a bit with the actual definition of an isomorphism. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Show that the "natural" map is bijective( i.e. 1-1 and onto)  and homomorphism.

Comment: What is the natural map?

Comment: Recall that $ \mathbb  Z$ is a cylic group generated by $1$,So for defining a   homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z \to d \mathbb Z $ it's enough to define on $1$ and then the homomorphism will take care of rest.So what is the natural choice for  $1$ in $ d \mathbb Z$?

Comment: 1 would be the natural choice. Does this mean that I will use induction?

Comment: Does $ d\mathbb Z$ contains $1$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily. I just realized. The natural choice for 1 in dZ would be d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism.
A homomorphism from $(G,*_G)$ ti $(H,*_H)$ is a function $\phi:G\to H$ which satisfies the following property: $$\phi(g_1*_Gg_2)=\phi(g_1)*_H\phi(g_2),$$ where $*_G$ and $*_H$ are the corresponding group operations and $g_1,g_2 \in G.$

As you and other people have noted, the "obvious" candidate function for our isomorphism is $$\phi(a)=d\times a.$$ We need to show this is a homomorphism first. Note that when $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $*$ is the group operation on both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $d\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. addition), $$\phi(a*b)=d\times (a*b)=d\times (a+b)=d\times a+d\times b=\phi(a)*\phi(b).$$
So our function indeed is homomorphic.

Now we need to show it is bijective, but that shouldn't be too hard as it has a natural inverse map $\phi^{-1}(da)=a,$ so I'll leave this up to you.

Answer (score 0):

An isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism, while a homomorphism between groups $G$ and $H$ is a map $\phi:G\to H$ such that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$.

The ("obvious") natural map is $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to d\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $\phi(a)=da$. You just need to show that is is injective, surjective, and a homomorphism.

Comment: I'm a little confused because if phi is defined by phi(a)=da then wouldn't phi(ab)=dab but phi(a)phi(b)=dadb which is different right?

Comment: @user139985, that is homomorphism property. You now have to show bijectivity.